# Maltlab resizing a image

Tags: matlab

So I am currently working through a workbook and I am having trouble understanding what my output is suppose to be.

Here is the question in the book.

> Read in the images *rice.png* and *cameraman.tif*
>   Find all pixels for which *rice* image has a value greater than that of the *cameraman* image and copy the corresponding pixel vlaues into the *cameraman* image.(Use the matlab function ***find***)

So here is my code for this

```
A=imread('rice.png');
B=imread('cameraman.tif');
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Assign the C variable to the find function to find all the value of in the
%Image A that are large than B

C=find(A>B);
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Displays all the values in A that are large than B
A(C);
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
D=imresize(B,size(C));


imshow(D)
```

But when I run the code I get the following

> Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 2%
>
> In images.internal.initSize (line 71)
>
> In imshow (line 328)
>
> In eight (line 13)

edit: I am now thinking I am not suppose to be resizing the image but using the pixel values to remove stuff from the image like so in my new code.

```
%Ex 2.4
A=imread('rice.png');
B=imread('cameraman.tif');


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Assign the C variable to the find function to find all the value of in the
%Image A that are large than B
C=find(A>B);
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Displays all the values in A that are large than B
%A(C);
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
B(C)=C; 
imshow(B)


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this what the question is asking for, as honeslty I am not sure

Comment: this is more about "how to use matlab" and not about "stats/math" so it is likely going to get voted to close.  Good news: you can ask an admin to port it over to "Stackoverflow" and folks there should answer it in a few minutes.  I would say "print out the size of B, and C".  I bet that c is a list of indices, not sizes, so maybe you are trying to make a thousand or million dimensional analog of a 2d image. You might just set the value of all pixels that aren't bigger to zero, and then plot it.  You might want to make a histogram of the difference in pixel intensities.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for tha adivce and will try what you said. How do I ask admin to port it over?

Comment: Your second try is on the right track. C is for indexing. You are now correctly using C to index into B where you need to make an assignment. But you are placing C itself into that spot. The question calls for you to place the same part of A into that spot. Can you figure out how to get the right part of A? You are close.

Comment: In this example you can use logical indexing or linear indexing, read this [article](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html) to understand the difference. I will use logical indexing, here you simply want `index = A>B;` and then simpyl replace the pixel, `B(index) = A(index)`...

Answer (score 0):

You are close. C contains the linear indices corresponding to the pixels where the intensity of A > B. B(C) = C assigns the linear indices as intensity, instead try to assign the values in A that corresponds to the indices C to B.

```
B(C) = A(C);
```